# Cluster analysis of barcoded DNA

Tags: r, perl, cluster-analysis, bioinformatics

I am using barcodes to tag mitochondrial DNA strands previous to PCR. The barcode sequences are not known, but they are 18 nucleotides long and directly proceed a known sequence (either CATCAT or TACTAC). Each DNA molecule will get a unique barcode identifier. Once the molecules undergo PCR, I need to cluster the sequences based on their 18 nucleotide barcode, and then subsequently align the sequences, per barcode.
To use an overly simple example, lets say I have 2 molecules that are going into a PCR reaction:

```
     CATCATBARCODE1SEQUENCE1
     TACTACBARCODE2SEQUENCE2
```

After amplification I have:

```
     CATCATBARCODE1SEQUENCE1
     CATCATBARCODE1SEQUENCE1 
     TACTACBARCODE2SEQUENCE2
     TACTACBARCODE2SEQUENCE2
```

I then want to search the section of sequence at position 6-13 and cluster them based on that window of sequence without changing the rest of the sequence, which would actually just look like what I have above. Then I could perform the alignment on the adjacent sequences.
Any ideas on how I could accomplish this clustering of a window of sequence, without taking into account the rest of the sequence? Thanks.

Comment: Using `dplyr` you could do something like `df %>% mutate(sub_seq = substr(dna_seq, start, end)) %>% group_by(sub_seq) %>% ...`

Comment: Hi Steve, I just started looking at dplyr. It seems like a great option. I will try what you suggested. If I need to, I can even format the data into tab separated columns, separating the CATCAT|TACTAC, barcode, and sequence and then use some of the functions in dplyr to organize them. I will keep looking into this...thanks for the tip.

Comment: If you can give more specifics on input and expected output, I may be able to give you a more concrete example.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I have a folder of fast5 files that I can convert to fasta, and then trim the sequences to be flanked by the known CATCAT|TACTAC. I then send all the sequences to a txt file. separated by new lines. I am not sure exactly what the output format should be because I have't arrived at the clustering/aligning method yet, but I figured I could work with a large text file of sequences...

Comment: Do you have what you need from the `dplyr` suggestion or is there something more specific that is still needed ?

Comment: Hi Steve, I am still looking around at dplyr. I also found Algorithm::Kmeans today on CPAN, which also looks like it might be useful. The rest of my code up to this point is in perl, so if that does the trick, I might stick with that. Thanks so much for all your help. I will follow up with you once my code is complete!

Comment: Hi Steve, I checked out dplyr. It doesn't offer any statistical manipulation if I understand the documentation associated with the module. It is good at clustering and manipulating columns of data, but can't perform a Kmeans or PAM test for example in the clustering. I am looking now at Algorithm::KMeans and Algorithm::Cluster, although they work on numerical input. I have been having trouble with them reading and using csv files that I have of number matrixes. I am starting to get desperate.

Comment: For future reference, you should just include the input and output you want and show what you've tried. All of the experimental design details and acronyms take away from the question. I understand what you are saying, but this is not a biology-oriented site, so most of your audience will stop reading after the first sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback SES. I was only trying to be as helpful as possible. I would rather err on the side of providing too much information, but point well taken.

Answer (score 0):

Overly simplified R code, but seems to do what you ask:

```
seqs <- c('CATCATBARCODE1SEQUENCE1',
         'CATCATBARCODE1SEQUENCE1',
         'TACTACBARCODE2SEQUENCE2',
         'TACTACBARCODE2SEQUENCE2' )

clusters <- list()

for (seq in seqs) {
  barcode <- substr(seq, 7, 14)
  if (!is.null(clusters[[barcode]])) {
    clusters[[barcode]] <- append(clusters[[barcode]], seq)
  } else {
    clusters[[barcode]] <- c(seq)
  }
}

print(clusters)
```

prints:

```
$BARCODE1
[1] "CATCATBARCODE1SEQUENCE1" "CATCATBARCODE1SEQUENCE1"

$BARCODE2
[1] "TACTACBARCODE2SEQUENCE2" "TACTACBARCODE2SEQUENCE2"
```

Comment: Hi Vince, thanks for the suggestion. I tried this and got a lot of errors, such as "unless use of numeric lt (<) in void context at line 10". Line 10 is the for (seq in seqs){ line. Also, "print (...) interpreted as function at line 18". Line 18 is the print (clusters) statement. Also, "unquoted string "clusters" may clash with future reserved word at line 18". And "syntax error at line 10 near "){". And "Bareword "seqs" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at line 8". Line 8 is the first line of the code.

Comment: What are you running the code with... R or perl? It is R code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can already obtain sequences starting like [CATCATBARCODEX] what I would do is just to process it in python. If your sequence starts are not the same then you may need to search for CATCAT and discard those that look to be in the wrong position. There may be some issue if the number of barcodes is very large but I think for something on the order of 100,000 simple methods should work.

Anyways, once you find the CATCAT what I would do is just to build up a dictionary of barcodes and start filtering. Then you can just rip off this first part of the sequences and align using whatever methods (I had a barcode project and using custom genome with bowtie was convenient).

let's say you need to find this sequence instead of just starting with it, in python a solution would be like

```
my_dict= {}
for seq in seqs:
     idx = seq.find("CATCAT")
     idx2 = seq.find("TACTAC")
     if idx==-1 and idx2==-1:continue
     # here you need to consider the location of idx and idx2, both may be present, sequence needs to be long enough etc
     barcode = seq[idx+6, idx+6+18]
     # you may want to shorten the barcode or encode it to a string
     if barcode in my_dict: 
          my_dict[barcode]=1 
     else : 
          my_dict[barcode]+=1;
     seq=seq[idx+24:]
```

In addition to the counting you can 1) append sequences to a fasta file per barcode or 2) assign the barcode as annotation to a large fasta file.

Regardless you probably want to strip down the sequence to simplify the downstream analysis.